# How to override a function call in Python?

Tags: python, overriding

I've something like this:

```
import os
from node import Node

def make_sum(num,done):
    for i in range(0,100):
        num = num + 1
    done(num)

def result(num):
    print num
    return num

node = Node()
node.register(make_sum(20,result))
result(25)
```

and `node.py` is this:

```
import os

    class Node():

        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def register(self,obj):
            print obj
```

What I want to do is this, that the `make_sum()` function call should happen from inside the `register()` function. But currently it gets called while making the `register()` function call.

Is such a thing possible to do it in python, where you can do a forward declaration of a function but call it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `make_sum` function as an argument to `register` method:

```
node.register(make_sum, 20, result)
```

then, call it in the method:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def register(self, f, num, done):
        print f(num, done)
```

Also, you can use `lambda`:

```
node.register(lambda: make_sum(20, result))
```

In this case you don't need to pass arguments at all:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def register(self, f):
        print f()
```

Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Maybe also worth to point out that if the OP can't change `register` signature he can subclass the `Node` class and override the method with the appropriate signature (and obviously use the derived class!)

Comment: Hah! I've implemented that already. Thought there would be a better way of doing it than this. Is there?

Comment: To add on to here, I was looking for a more function way of making this happen.

Comment: @Guandalino Can you expand a bit more on this with some code? Will be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Hick could you please first explain why do you want to make `make_sum()` function call inside the `register()` method?

Comment: @alecxe I want register function to act like a task stack. So, if I'm registering a function call, then it should stay in the stack and not get called till I do a pop operation on the queue. What I've currently written, is half way there, where I want the function declarations to added a stack maintained by the Node class via the register function

Comment: @Hick I don't want to edit @alecxe answer so I'll elaborate here. If you can't change the `register()` signature in Node directly, because for example Node is coming from 3rd-party package, you can create your `MyNode(Node)` class, override `register()` with the new signature there and finally use `MyNode` instead of `Node` in your code.

Comment: @Hick ok, so `Node` class is somewhat a collection of functions that will be executed later, on queue pop, right? Then, passing functions with arguments to the class method sounds ok to me. Why don't you like these approach? You can also use `*args`, `**kwargs` for an arbitrary function arguments.

Comment: I obviously can change the register signature, as it is me who is writing the library. What @alexce suggested is something that I had already implemented but it doesn't exactly reflect much of functional programming, something that I'm trying to achieve in python. Isn't it possible to do a forward declaration of a function and store it in a task to call later?

Comment: @alecxe I absolutely like this approach and was one of the first things that I implemented. Though, it seemed rather weird for me, as I wanted to resemble more of a function call than a dict being passed around. Hence, I came on SO to find if there is a solution that I've no idea of.

Comment: @Hick I've added another option: using `lambda`. Please check. By the way, there is a [Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) module, take a look, might be what you need for storing functions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like `functools.partial` is the more direct way of getting what you want;

```
from functools import partial

node.register(partial(make_sum, 20,result))
```

`partual(make_sum, 20, result)` makes a new function that, when called, has the arguments `20` and `result` automatically added.

It supports `*` and `**` as well as namd arguments:

```
loud_printer = partial(print, *(1, 2, 3), end="")

loud_printer
#>>> functools.partial(<built-in function print>, 1, 2, 3, end='')

loud_printer()
#>>> 1 2 3
```